# Disabling the play/pause button until there is a connection with the audio

Tags: javascript, button, input, form-submit

Clicking Set on an empty text input should not change the svg to pause

How would I set it up so that if the input area has no **.src stream** in it, clicking on it will not change the play svg to pause.

For it to change there has to be an **.src stream** in there.

**Code:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/23/

This is an audio stream: `http://hi5.1980s.fm/;`

The **pause button** **should not** be able to be shown without an **src stream** in it.

What's a good way to be able to do this?

I want to disable the play/pause button until there is a connection with the audio.

[image]

```
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const player = document.getElementById("player");
    const button = document.getElementById("button");
    const value = document.getElementById("input");
    const sent = document.getElementById("sent");
    const input = document.getElementById("clear");

    function playPauseIcon(play) {
        if (play) {
            button.classList.add("is-playing");
        } else {
            button.classList.remove("is-playing");
        }
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            playPauseIcon(true);
        } else {
            player.pause();
            playPauseIcon(false);
        }
    });
    button.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
        if (evt.detail > 1) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
    sent.addEventListener("click", function () {
        player.src = value.value;
        player.volume = 1.0;
        playPauseIcon(true);     
    });
    input.addEventListener("click", function () {
        value.value = "";
          button.classList.remove("is-playing");
          player.pause();
    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: You mean adding condition `player.src!==''` ?

Comment: Yes, how would I write that into the code?

Comment: Are you able to help with this? I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take one variable and use it  on [`onloadstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart) event of audio

```
let canPlay = false;
player.onloadstart  = function() {
    canPlay = true;
  };
```

and check it like this

```
 button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(!canPlay){return};
    if (player.paused) {
      player.play();
      playPauseIcon(true);
    } else {
      player.pause();
      playPauseIcon(false);
    }
  });
```

change it back on clear

```
input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    value.value = "";
    button.classList.remove("is-playing");
    player.pause();
    canPlay = false;
  }, false);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/26/)

Comment: If you click set with no stream in it, the play button still changes to pause. I want to prevent that from happening. It should only change when there is a valid stream in it. https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/26/

Comment: When clicking 'set' with no stream inside, the play button should stay as 'Play' and not change to 'Pause'. How would that functionality be added to the code?https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/26/

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith let me check

Comment: Now, when I put a stream inside, the play button doesn't change to Pause on first click.  https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/33/

Comment: When I put in a stream, hit 'Set' the Play svg doesn't change to the Pause button. https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/33/

Comment: jslint is telling me this: Unexpected expression '!=' in statement position. player.src != ""; https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/49/

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith I can not help you with each and every line you need to understand what you need to do next. just change != to !== and it should be ok

Comment: That gave me this: Unexpected expression '!==' in statement position.
        player.src !== "";

Comment: Why exactly is this needed in the code? player.src != ''; / If I remove it from the code, it works the same way. / Do you see any difference at all, whether it is in the code or not? https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/52/

Comment: If you don't see a difference, maybe it was written wrong, or it's not needed in the code.

Comment: Maybe this condition doesn’t even exist.
player.src != "";
player.src !== "";

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith yes you can remove that if you want

Comment: Right now, any letters I type into the input will cause the 'Play' button to change to 'Pause.'

Could I set it up so that the Play button would only change to the Pause button if the audio link is working?

https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/62/

Comment: If the value is an incorrect stream link, the 'Play' button still changes to 'Pause.'

This is what I was trying to prevent from happening.

Pressing 'Set' should not cause the Play button to change from 'Play' to 'Pause' if the audio is not working.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/124/

Comment: What if I changed player.onloadstart to player.oncanplay instead? https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/132/ That seems to have worked. Play button does not change from Play to Pause when the stream is not valid. h://hi5.1980s.fm/

Comment: Which should be used here? oncanplay https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/ OR oncanplaythrough https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/144/ A radio stream would be considered what?

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith ask new question if you have any, I can not help you with each and every line